# Emulating Windows High Contrast Mode (forced-colors: dark) on a site

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, accessibility, high-contrast

I've noticed that Chrome has the ability to activate an emulation of forced-colors: dark (aka Windows High Contrast Mode). I'd like to add a button to enable high contrast mode to a site, so users can do so rapidly if they choose to.

So far the best I've managed is writing a ton of CSS that doesn't work anywhere near as well as Chrome's built in emulation.

Comment: Specifically, I'm looking to activate "forced-colors: active" and "prefers-color-scheme: dark" (and light, ideally).

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if there's no way to do this programmatically - at least on Windows (this was originally an IE feature after all), the colors it picks are based on some system colors the OS defines when high contrast mode is on. I imagine those colors are either undefined, or not really high-contrast, if the OS isn't in that mode.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it's not doable. A shame-the testing functionality is built right in to the browser. No reason not to make it programmatically accessible. The colors are definitely defined, as there are multiple theme options.